# How to create updates system for users?

Tags: python, version-control

I have [project](https://github.com/laszlowaty/astroConverter) on github. Few people are using it. I want to create a system, that will allow those people to update to current version. I was thinking about creating script, that will fetch `*.zip` file of my project from github, unpack it and later `open()` every file and check every line (`if x == line`). In case of `!=` i want to swap files.

My question is: is this the right way to do this? Or is it better to just grab `*.zip` and force-swap every project file?

Comment: *"is this the right way to do this?"* - no. If you created a proper `setup.py`, your users would be able to `pip install` and `--upgrade` as appropriate. Also, note that your directory would generally be organised such that your actual package is in a sub-directory - see e.g. http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/08/16/open-sourcing-a-python-project-the-right-way/ for how to get set up.

Comment: Why don't you use git branching??

Comment: @jester112358 I am the only one, that is creating this project. Other people are just using this program in their research
@jonrsharpe I don't want users to use `cmd` commands or such. I need them to click `update` option and voila.

Comment: So why it's not working if they test pull the master branch and their version gets updated if there is a newer release?

Comment: @jester112358 Oh, they can't do that. They don't have git installed. They are just users. I want them to `one-click` update program.

Comment: Then create and distribute a proper installer; why reinvent the `.whl` (little Python packaging joke for you, there)? You don't think they can `pip install` but expect them to run the program with `python` on the command line?

Comment: @jonrsharpe i've made `*.bat` file for them ;-) I was trying to make .exe and installer using `cx_freeze` and `py2exe`, but it doesn't work well with `astropy`. Besides, it would force them, to reinstall program every time new update is ready. I need a way, to pass them path in easy way.

Comment: You should probably have a look at https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/